# how to make footer of reports fixed in the bottom

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I have created a custom module . My footer in the reports is not fixed in footers I have tried several solutions but nothing, either it goes up or it decent towards the next page if my sale order contains several products. If my sale order is composed of two pages my footer is displayed on the second page only because it is breaking down.I'm using odoo 9 .Any help please ?

```
 <div class="footer">

                <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
  <small>
                        <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline">
                            <li t-if="company.phone">Phone:
                                <span t-field="company.phone"/>
                            </li>


                            <li t-if="company.fax and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>

                            <li t-if="company.fax">Fax:
                                <span t-field="company.fax"/>
                            </li>


                            <li t-if="company.email and company.fax or company.email and company.phone">
                                &amp;bull;
                            </li>

                            <li t-if="company.vat">TVA:
                                <span t-field="company.vat"/>
                            </li>


                            <li t-if="company.company_registry">&amp;bull;</li>
                            <li t-if="company.company_registry">RC:
                                <span t-field="company.company_registry"/>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </small>
  <small>
                              <ul class="list-inline">
                            <t t-set="nbr_page" t-value="1"/>
                            <li>Page:</li>
                            <t t-set="compteur" t-value="nbr_page+1"/>
                            <li>
                                <span class="page"/>
                                <t t-esc="nbr_page"/>
                            </li>
                            /
                            <t t-esc="nbr_page"/>
                            <li>
                                <span class="topage"/>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </small>



                <t t-set="nbr_page" t-value="1"/>

                    <t t-set="compteur" t-value="nbr_page+1"/>
                    <!--<t t-esc="nbr_page"/>-->

                <!--<t t-if="company.custom_footer">-->
                    <!--<span t-raw="company.rml_footer"/>-->
                <!--</t>-->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by adding tag **style**  in **div class="footer" style="position:absolute;bottom:-1115px"**